# Ag-Grid Cell Render don't display buttons correctly when used with Angular material tab

Tags: angular, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular10

I just started to use ag-grid in one of my projects and I created a Cell Renderer to display buttons in my "actions" columns, as you can see below:

[image]

Everything works fine but after I moved the grid inside of an Angular material I observed a strange behavior. If you navigate to the second tab and then you go back. The buttons are pushed out of the table:

[image]

You can check the behavior on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpkk94?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html).

Any help or ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution when reading [material tab documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples):

```
<mat-tab label="First">
   <ng-template matTabContent>
    <ag-grid-angular ...></ag-grid-angular>
   </ng-template>
  </div>
</mat-tab>
```

You can wrap the tab content in "ng-template matTabContent".
This will inject the html structure for this tab only when the tab is active.

Answer (score 1):

Weird... the column content is put in a completely different position in the DOM. But it works if you put a div around the ag-grid:

```
<mat-tab label="First">
  <div>
    <ag-grid-angular ...></ag-grid-angular>
  </div>
</mat-tab>
```

Don't ask me why... ;-)